# Django ListView class pagination filter query not effecting in pagination

Tags: django

```
   i failed to include pagination in django list view
```

pagination count shows without filter query any idea about to include fileter query in pagination calculation?

```
    assets_list = Assets.objects.filter(site=self.site,type__icontains="Asset")

    page = self.request.GET.get('page', 1)

    paginator = Paginator(assets_list, self.paginate_by)
    try:
        asset_data = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        asset_data = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        asset_data = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context['assets'] = asset_data
```

Comment: I'm seeing you `try except` code is the same as the `get_page` function on `Paginator` class. However, are you sure about the query you are doing?

Comment: This  [article](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2018/10/18/filtering-and-pagination-django/) may help you..